# uninitialized constant Requests (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, module, helper

I put some code in **spec/support/request_helpers.rb**

```
module Requests
  module JsonHelpers
    def json
      @json ||= JSON.parse(response.body)
    end
  end
end
```

Then I added config line to **spec/rails_helper.rb** to access that code from my spec.

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.include Requests::JsonHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

So when I run my spec from **spec/controller/tasks_controller_spec.rb** I get the following error.

```
/spec/rails_helper.rb:16:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Requests (NameError)
```

How to solve it?

My spec has `require 'rails_helper'` on the top.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have already added `require` your support folder?
Add to your `spec_helper.rb`:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if Rails.env.production?
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'

# with many helpers
Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/support/*.rb"].each {|f| require f }
# or only one   
# require 'support/request_helpers'

ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
# some code here
```

[`About spec/support`](http://ryanbigg.com/2013/02/about-spec-support/)